# Spring JPA error issue of "Property of @IdClass not fund in entity"

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want to have a table that maps to two different tables and I have this error issue.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Property of @IdClass not found in entity com.susanghan.spotrightspring.photo.domain.MemberSpotPhoto: SpotPhotoId
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.fillComponent(AnnotationBinder.java:2793) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindIdClass(AnnotationBinder.java:2919) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.mapAsIdClass(AnnotationBinder.java:1052) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:778) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.processEntityHierarchies(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:225) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.processEntityHierarchies(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:239) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:282) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1460) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1494) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
```

**This is `MemberSpotPhotoPK`**

```java
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MemberSpotPhotoPK implements Serializable {

    private static final Long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Long memberSpotId;
    private Long SpotPhotoId;
}
```

**And this is the `MemberSpotPhoto` that uses `MemberSpotPhotoPK` as primary key.**

```java
@Getter
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@IdClass(MemberSpotPhotoPK.class)
public class MemberSpotPhoto extends BaseTimeEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long memberSpotId;

    @Id
    @Column(insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long spotPhotoId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "member_spot_id", referencedColumnName = "member_spot_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private MemberSpot memberSpot;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "spot_photo_id", referencedColumnName = "spot_photo_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private SpotPhoto spotPhoto;

    private Byte order;

    @Builder
    public MemberSpotPhoto(Long memberSpotId, Long spotPhotoId, Byte order) {
        this.memberSpotId = memberSpotId;
        this.spotPhotoId = spotPhotoId;
        this.order = order;
    }
}
```

**And these are two `MemberSpot` and `SpotPhoto` which are mapped to `MemberSpotPhoto`**

```java
@Getter
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
public class MemberSpot extends BaseTimeEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "member_spot_id")
    private Long id;
    
    ....
}
```

```java
@Getter
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
public class SpotPhoto extends BaseTimeEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "spot_photo_id")
    private Long id;

    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a typo. In your `MemberSpotPhotoPK` class you have a field named `SpotPhotoId`, with capital "S" at the start. Rename it to `spotPhotoId` and everything should be fine!